# db isolation level lost update prevent

Tags: database, spring-data-jpa

I wrote the following transaction using spring data jpa.

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean removeAvailableStock(Long itemId, Long quantity) {
        ItemEntity itemEntity = itemRepository.findById(itemId).orElseThrow(NoSuchItemException::new);

        itemEntity.removeAvailableStock(quantity);

        return true;
    }
```

I tested the method in a multithreaded environment.

It caused a race condition.

So I set the transaction isolation level to Repeatable read level or Serializable level.

However, Race conditions continued to occur.

The only solution to this was to specify LockMode to findById Method in the repository.

Many documents say that transaction isolation level can solve the lost Update problem.

However, the transaction isolation level did not solve the concurrency problem.

Why doesn't the isolation level resolve lost updates in this situation?

What do many documents refer to as the level of isolation?

If the isolation level doesn't solve the concurrency problem, what's the purpose?

The test environment was h2 db

Comment: Why do you think the isolation level would matter? What does `removeAvailableStock` do? How does your entity look like?

Comment: @JensSchauder This is removeAvailableStock(Long qyt) method

this.stock -= qty;